# How should I combine two paths including backwards relative paths?

Tags: c#, path

I have an absolute path, and a relative path, and I want to combine the two, is there any built-in way?

The relative path can be as well "`../../aa2/file.exe`".

(`path.combine` does not support it - which is pretty bizarre by itself.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(abs, rel))`

Comment: wow! would never thought about it.. but I hope it's fast, because from the glance at the code of it at reflector, it does quite a work with windows..